# GPX for custom map

Tags: gpx

How to design  a gpx file for a custom map?

Answer (score 4):

A [GPX file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) usually contains GPS waypoints, tracks or routes or any combination thereof. The gpx format itself has nothing to do with the representation of such data on a map.

Answer (score 1):

***GPX**(the GPS Exchange Format)* is a light-weight XML data format for the interchange of GPS data (waypoints, routes, and tracks) between applications and Web services on the Internet.

Click [here](http://gpx-poi.com/) to visit **Online GPX file generator**.

Click [here](http://www.maplorer.com/view_gpx.html) to visit Custom **Online GPX viewer**.

To know more about GPX click [here](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/) is the schema documentation of GPX file. It will help you to create a valid file. It doesn't depend on the type of map.